# Unable to import certificate to login Keychain (OS X 10.13.5)

Tags: macos, azure, certificate, keychain

I'm trying to add a VPN certificate for Azure, but when I open the cert to add to the login keychain, it does not actually add it. Dragging and dropping does nothing as well, nor can I add it via the command line via:

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain VpnServerRoot.crt
```

There are also no errors generated, or output of any kind when trying to add it. I've heard this may be a bug with OS X, but haven't seen a solution anywhere.

Comment: whats the error u are seeing? Can I get a screenshot of that?

Comment: There are no errors, no output at all. I double click to open the certificate, Keychain opens up but nothing gets imported.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I see your problem. You have just the .cert file. which requires a private/public key in order to add it to the keychain.

Get that and try to add it.

More info on Azure docs site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-certificates-point-to-site